# What remedies exist for illegally evicted tenants in Florida?

Tags: tenant, florida, eviction

Can one get an injunction of reinstatement? Are there criminal sanctions for the instigator of the illegal eviction? Anything else?

Comment: Generally once you're out, you're out.  Judges are very reluctant to compel people who hate each other to work together when there are market solutions. Your recourse is most likely limited to money damages or getting the landlord to stop saying you were evicted (i.e. eviction removed from your credit report).

Comment: Not enough facts to know. In way way was the eviction illegal? Was the tenant in default? Was there a right on the merits to continue living there? Was service of process defective? Was there an eviction moratorium? Did he landlord act intentionally wrongfully or negligently? Was it a Section 8 lease? Was the person disabled or in military service? Did a court order wrongfully issue or was there no court order and just self-help? Was there a breach of the peace in doing so? Did a sheriff or deputy preside? Was there fraud in or out of court? Were there damages and is so what were they?

Comment: No the tenant was not in either breach nor default. The eviction was completely arbitrary.  No attempt to serve notice was made. It was just a blatantly lawless extralegal action. There was a right on the merit to keep living there.